# Pourquoi est-ce que le mot "consultant" a une définition "actuelle" contraire à sa définition "ancienne" ?

Tags: sens, terminologie

Dans le domaine de l'informatique, il y a énormément de "consultants".

Dans ce contexte, la personne étant le consultant est consulté par une autre entité et le consultant donne son avis.

D'après la définition qui me semblait logique, ici, le consultant est l'autre entité et le consulté est la personne qui donne son avis. Or, c'est tout à fait l'inverse.

Si je prends d'autres mots, comme habitant, militant, etc. ces mots qualifient l'entité qui effectue l'action.
Un habitant habite, un militant milite.

Mais pourquoi est-ce qu'un consultant ne consulte pas ? Car la définition de consulter est: *Demander avis, conseil à*

Remarque: d'après [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/consultant#), il y a un sens désuet pour consultant:

*(Désuet) Celui qui vient consulter ou qui demande un conseil dans une consultation*

Ma question est donc: Pour quelle raison est-ce que "consultant" se voit attribuer un sens différent que les autres mots ayant le suffixe *ant* ?

PS: Je n'ai pas la moindre idée du/des "tags" que je dois appliquer à cette question et il n'y a pas de suggestion.

Comment: Interesting. In English this kind of transposition of the agent is common and promiscuous. Watering hole, witching hour, looking glass, building blocks, fighting words, sleeping pills, etc. etc. all have participles with an agent other than the noun they modify. But when I try to think of examples in French, the grammar is not parallel (e.g. not *pâte modelante* but *pâte à modeler*...)

Answer (score 4):

Un élément semble se trouver dans la page [*consulter* du cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consulter), mais sur le sens B :

> B.− [En parlant d'un médecin ou d'un avocat] Donner des consultations, recevoir les clients dans son cabinet. Ce médecin, cet avocat consulte tous les jours de cinq à six heures (Lar. 19e).

Avec ce sens du verbe, le participe présent substantivé *consultant* peut donc désigner celui qui donne des consultations.

On retrouve d'ailleurs les deux sens contraires de consultant dans la page [cnrtl de consultant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consultant) :

> A.− Vieilli ou rare. Personne qui consulte, qui demande avis et conseil dans une consultation. (...)
>
> B.− [Le plus souvent en appos. spécifiante] Personne qui donne des consultations (médicales ou juridiques).

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe consulter à deux sens principaux, c'est le premier ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consulter):  Délibérer avec soi-même, en âme et conscience, réfléchir, peser le pour et le contre avant de prendre une décision / Délibérer avec d'autres, pour prendre une décision commune) qui correspond au sens habituel de consultant.

Un consultant est une personne (initialement un médecin ou un avocat) qui donne (rédige) des [consultations](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consultation), c'est à dire le plus souvent un document écrit où elle donne son avis d'expert sur un sujet donné.

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consultant) donne trois exemples qui correspondent à cette définition:

- un avocat consultant ne plaide pas mais donne des conseils
- un médecin consultant est appelé par un médecin traitant
- une sage-femme consultante ne pratique pas les accouchements

Le sens s'est élargi puis spécialisé à partir des années 70, d'abord aux des sociétés de conseil en gestion, finances, etc. puis aux sociétés proposant des services en informatique, très certainement sous l'influence de l'anglais.